# How to get the index in an array in cypress

Tags: cypress

how to do this in array? How to get the index per log?

```
code : 

 cy.fixture('weekly_report0.json').then((data) => {

      cy.addContext('Total Calls:') 

      for (var index in data) {
      
            cy.log(data[index].__EMPTY_1)

      }
  


 })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crJ1H.png)

I wanted to get the index of the log which is equal to "Summary"

Comment: `if(data[index].__EMPTY_1) == 'Summary' 
 cy.log(index);`   // ??

Comment: hello , its okay now .. i used lodash libray

Comment: @Jhenylyn- please close the question with the answer, which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working with a json file.
So, let me show this test first, which runs perfectly:

```
   it('just testing', () => {
    var jsonVar = {
        name: "pepe",
        lastName: "ruiz",
        salary: 1234
    }

   var arrayData = Object.values(jsonVar)

   arrayData.forEach((val, index)=>{
        cy.log(`index: ${index} and value ${val}`)
    })

});
```

Now, I will try to adapt it in this way:

```
cy.fixture('weekly_report0.json').then((data) => {

  cy.addContext('Total Calls:') 

  var arrayData = Object.values(data)

   arrayData.forEach((val, index)=>{
        cy.log(`index: ${index} and value ${val}`)
    })

 })
```